# I need a space in which every sequence converges

Tags: general-topology

> Is there any (nontrivial) topological space in which every sequence converges ,and why ??

Comment: Pick $X=\{x\}$ singleton set.

Comment: (^The comment was posted before OP edited it to say nontrivial.)

Answer (score 5):

Recall the definition of convergence: $x_n$ converges to $x$ if for every open set $U$ including $x$ there is some $n_0$ such that for every $n>n_0$, $x_n\in U$.

What happens when you have $x$ which is an element of every non-empty open set?

Comment: It means the topology generated by $\{x\}$, $x\in X$ = Discrete topology

Comment: Your comment doesn't make much sense. Moreover if you want a discrete space in which every sequence converges, then you have to have a singleton and a trivial topology.

Comment: did not get any specific topology following your hint !

Comment: Read it again...

Answer (score 4):

Take any space with the trivial topology, i.e. the only open sets are the empty set and the whole space.

Comment: Sorry I have edit to nontrivial space

Comment: @AsafKaragila It should be nice to characterize such spaces.

Comment: @DayanaChesslo You can find a non trivial one following Asaf suggestion.

Comment: @azarel: That would be nice. Another nice thing would be to find a nontrivial example where all sequences converge, but not all long sequences/nets converge. :-)

Comment: From the top of my mind, I'd say that $X$ has the property that every sequence converges if and only if the intersection of every $\aleph_0$ non-empty open sets is non-empty.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : What about $X = \omega_1$ where the open sets have the form $[x , \omega_1)$ for some $0\leq x < \omega_1$? Is this a topological space?  If so, does it satisfy your condition?  If so, does the sequence $\{1,2,1,2,1,2,\ldots\}$ converge?

Comment: @Stefan: Yes. The space is not Hausdorff and one fan show that $1$ is a limit point of this sequence.

Comment: @Stefan: To see my above comment (which was written from my phone) is true, note that there are exactly two open sets which include $1$, those are $[1,\omega_1)$ and $[2,\omega_1)$. In fact, $0$ is another limit point of this sequence. Indeed $0$ is a limit point of every sequence.